# Converting to same child objects in MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I need to convert objects that have children in this kind of structure

```
A --> C
|     |
v     v
B --> D
```

Currently I am using imported converters to convert both B and C and they both in their turn convert their own copy of D resulting in something like this

```
A --> C --> D1
|
v
B
|
v
D2
```

Is there a way to solve this kind of structure using mapstruct?

Comment: Please share [mcve]

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko sure, I should have done that, I'll do it as soon as I can